# XBEE/ZIGBEE Wireless Module API <- VB Express:When I send an ND command to a remote endpoint I get?

Tags: api, vb.net-2010, wireless, xbee, zigbee

when I send an API ND command to a remote endpoint I get ???

When I send an API ND command from a VB program using the following packet;

7E 00 05 08 01 4E 44 00 64

I get;

7E 05 3F 14 E4 41 3F

Its a response -- but not as I know it. Neither the checksum "3F" or command length "05" are comprehensible to me. On the other hand if I wait for more bytes by setting "Serialport1.ReceivedBytesThreshold" (threshold: 10 bytes in buffer > event is fired) to 10 the "SerialPort1.ReadExisting()" statement times out. Any suggestions for decoding? Both coordinator and endpoint are XBEE PRO S2Bs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it makes sense to send `ATND` as a remote AT command, and it will probably be ignored on the remote node, or trigger node discovery at that node with the responses staying local.

It looks like your response is possibly dropping null bytes (0x00), like the MSB of length, and one more in the packet itself.  I'm not familiar with a frame type of 0x3F though -- is it documented for that XBee module you're using?

After a node discovery, you should see multiple AT Response frames (type 0x88?) come back over some time (based on `ATNT`, I believe), until you get one with a short payload (indicating discovery is complete).

Comment: I take this to mean that I should try some try a more mainstream test such as reading a remote's digital/analog pins. Correct?

Comment: Yes, query some other value.  It can be one of the I/O lines, the firmware version, or even `ATIS` to read all of the inputs.